# Scrolling ability in a fixed div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a div that slide from the left 100% once you press a button. In that div it will display my menu for the site. The issue I am having is when on a small browser size the content gets covered and you are unable to see the rest of the links.

My div #slidingMenu has a fixed positioning and I gave the div an overflow-y:scroll. Once I added that code I did have the ability to scroll. But the problem was #slidingMenu now slides out displaying a white bar (scrollbar). Is there a way to have the main scrollbar of the browser control my menu in #slidingMenu when I scroll?

Here is the css and the file http://jsfiddle.net/bC5zh/6/

```
 #footer{
  background-color:#999;
  width:100%;
  height:50px;
  position:absolute;
  top:100%;
  margin-top:-50px;
  line-height:50px;
 }
 #toggle{
  color:#FFF;
  margin-left:50px;
  cursor:pointer;
 }
 #slidingMenu{
  position:fixed;
  background-color:#999;
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  top:0;
  left:-100%;
  overflow-y:scroll;
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding in your css

```
 #slidingMenu::-webkit-scrollbar { 
   display: none; 
 }
```

this will hide the scrollbar giving you the ability to still scroll on the site.

Answer (score 2):

You would use

```
overflow-y:auto;
```

To remove the scrollbar but allow for scrolling when inner content is overflowing, updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bC5zh/7/)

For a smoother scroll on WebKit mobile devices you can use

```
 -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
```

Which mimics default iOS scrolling [reference](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/momentum-scrolling-on-ios-overflow-elements/)

Comment: That is almost what I am looking for. Is there a way to not display a secondary scrollbar and only have the main scroll bar control the divs content? @Last1Here

Comment: Not that I know while use `position: fixed;` you could re-do your layout and use `position: relative;` there is also ways to do it with javascript I imagine

Comment: @user3756781, You can, but not when your div is fixed/absolute. The quickest fix for you would be to change the position property on sliding in/ out: check Last1Here's [updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kevinvanlierde/bC5zh/9/)

Comment: that works but does not keep with the 100% height of the site just the screen. When you scroll down I need for the content on the div to scroll but always stay on top when the full site scrolls, also keeping the div background at 100% height @Tyblitz